# Yet another About ajax.net update panels performance thread

Tags: performance, ajax.net, panels

Good day,

we just moved from asp.net 1.1 to asp.net 2.0. We are using ajax update panels.

In an Apress book (Pro asp.net 2008) , I've read that when you use the updatepanel, you don't reduce the acount of bandwidth sent, because the entire page is still sent.

That in mind, I've also read on many websites that it is better to use multiple updatepanels instead of only one containing the entire page to 'reduce the amount of bandwidth sent'. In my opinion, there is a contradiction with the Apress book, and I was wondering what you guys think.

Is it better to use only one updatepanel containing the entire page, or many ones? The performance is my main concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how many parts of your page you want to be able to load separately.

Each panel = separate updateable part

Regards
K

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many parts of your page you want to be able to load separately, you'll need a panel for each part.

The complete viewstate is always sent with the postback to the server.

Regards
K